# React Native + Firebase signin Error: Undefind is not object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator')

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm attempting to create a simple app that allows users to register and login using Firebase as a backend.

I'm using Stephen Grider-ReactNativeCasts as a template and I implemented firebase as the backend somewhat successfully I think. I am able to signup and the user shows up in the user list on the firebase dashboard, but when I attempt to sign in I get the error: Undefind is not object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator').

This is what my signin looks like,

```html
var React = require('react-native');
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput
} = React;

var Parse = require('parse/react-native');
var Button = require('../common/button');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errorMessage: ''
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Sign In</Text>

        <Text style={styles.label}>Email:</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={this.state.email}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}
          />

        <Text style={styles.label}>Password:</Text>
        <TextInput
          secureTextEntry={true}
          style={styles.input}
          value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
          />

        <Text style={styles.label}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
        <Button text={'Sign In'} onPress={this.onPress} />
        <Button text={'I need an account...'} onPress={this.onSignupPress} />
      </View>
    );
  },
  onSignupPress: function() {
    this.props.navigator.push({name: 'signup'});
  },
  onPress: function() {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://reactapplogin.firebaseio.com");
    ref.authWithPassword({
      email    : this.state.email,
      password : this.state.password
    }, function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
        this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack({name: 'tweets'});
      }
    });
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  input: {
    padding: 4,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    margin: 5,
    width: 200,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 18
  }
});
```

I'm having issue with `this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack({name: 'tweets'});` not working, and I also have zero idea where these console logs show up in the emulator (using Genymotion/Android Studio Emulators) so debugging is proving a little hard. I've tried to connect to chrome but it keeps failing.

Anyhelp would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Stephen's project Github Page: https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReactNativeCasts/tree/master/authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with Firebase but with your implementation.
You don't have the navigator on your props because you are not using a navigator. In Stephen's project Github Page you can see the Navigator is rendered and the components get the navigator prop.

```
renderScene: function(route, navigator) {
    var Component = ROUTES[route.name]; // ROUTES['signin'] => Signin
    return <Component route={route} navigator={navigator} />;
},
render: function() {
    return (
      <Navigator
            style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{name: 'signin'}}
            renderScene={this.renderScene}
            configureScene={() => { return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight; }}
      />
);
```

**update**

Take a look at the [src/main.js](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReactNativeCasts/blob/master/authentication/src/main.js).
The rendered component is the react-native [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html). on the navigator you have a renderScene prop that calls renderScene function which returns the correct component according to the ROUTES object and passes it the navigator as a prop.

Comment: So I figured my issue was with my implementation, but I'm unsure exactly what and how to fix it. Could you maybe point me in the right direction, as I'm not sure what these means for fixing this. Thanks!

Comment: So this doesn't explain why some methods within the component can use the navigator prop and some can't. Within that same comp, I am calling it to switch to the signup screen so I know the prop can be reached. What am I missing here?

Comment: @EladKarni Ohh, I thought your navigator didn't work at all. So I think your context is changed inside the authWithPassword function. Can you try to set a const self = this; before calling authWithPassword and then inside authWithPassword use self.props.navigator, and see if it works?

Comment: Good idea! So I gave that a shot, and now I get a different error which is progress I guess haha

The new error is - `undefined is not a function (evaluation 'nextRouteStack.map(this.props.configureScene)')`

Comment: can u give more details? some code maybe..is this in you code, or navigator?

Comment: So I'm trying to get the `self.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack({name: 'tweets'});` to work. If I do `self.props.navigator.pop()` it works fine, but the other one to reset the stack doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any warnings or errors?
according to the docs it seems like the method accepts an array https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#immediatelyresetroutestack

Comment: Please read the docs of navigator. Undersand what u need to pass as props. You can also google immediatelyResetRouteStack and see many examples. :)

Comment: I'm an idiot! So I added the `[]`, but forgot to add self instead of this which caused some issues. After a little fiddling around, I managed to get it to work. It was looking for an array as you said, and I forgot to wrap it in `[` and `]`... Sorry!

Thanks to you, I can now sign-in, and sign-out! All I need is to somehow make something of this system haha!

Comment: cool, great :). If you don't need anything else on the subject, Please mark as answered.

Comment: Will do! Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the below change and your program should work,  `immediatelyResetRouteStack` accepts an `array` not an `object`

```
this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack({name: 'tweets'}); // wrong
this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{name: 'tweets'}]); // right
```